# Mensaje de error en Json

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tengo dos peticiones Ajax en un mismo archivo,  haciendo test por separado funcionan correctamente, estas son las peticiones, esta peticion carga los datos de una tabla.

```js
$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "notificaciones.php",
            async:true,
            //dataType: 'json', // Esta linea se comenta por que si lo activo deja de funcionar.
            data: { "Numero_Empleado": Numero_Empleado },
            success: function(Transferencia) {
                //console.log(Transferencia);
                //alert(Transferencia);
                var datosTransferencia = JSON.parse(Transferencia);

                for(var i in datosTransferencia.Transferencia){
                    // Aquí lleva otro código
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
```

y tengo esta otra petición carga los datos de otra tabla.

```js
$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "notificaciones.php",
            async:true,
            //dataType: 'json',  // Esta linea se comenta por que si lo activo deja de funcionar.
            data: { "Numero_Empleado": Numero_Empleado },
            success: function(Asignacion,) {
                //console.log(data);
                //alert(data);
                var datosAsignacion = JSON.parse(Asignacion);

                for(var i in datosAsignacion.Asignacion){
                    // Aquí lleva otro código

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

el detalle es que ambos códigos me traen el resultado de la consulta a la cual se le realizan las peticiones, el problema que se presenta es que al momento que se cargan los dos resultados del Json marca un error la salida es esta:

```
{"Asignacion":[{"Notificacion":"1","Cantidad":"2","Nombre":"NOMBRE REGISTRADO EN LA BD"}]}{"Transferencia":[{"Notificacion":"1","Cantidad":"2","Nombre":"NOMBRE REGISTRADO EN LA BD"}]}
```

El error que me indica es el siguiente: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 145"  y me lo pone dos veces señalando el mismo error, checando en internet identifique que una persona indica que el soluciono este problema colocando una "," entre las dos "textos" Json pero esto lo lograba por que el hacia de manera manual sus "textos".  `{"Asignacion":[{"Notificacion_Asig":"1","Cantidad":"2","Nombre":"NOMBRE REGISTRADO EN LA BD"}]},{"Transferencia":[{"Notificacion_Trans":"1","Cantidad":"2","Nombre":"NOMBRE REGISTRADO EN LA BD"}]}`

Existe alguna manera de clavar esa coma entre los dos "textos".

La otra idea que se me ocurre es en una sola consulta obtener los datos de las dos tablas y luego en el script dividir la función en dos partes.

Bueno haber si alguien tiene alguna idea al respecto.

Saludos y Gracias!!! de Antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregar una coma entre las dos llaves no funciona, porque no genera un JSON válido:

```js
let str = `{"Asignacion":[{"Notificacion":"1","Cantidad":"2","Nombre":"NOMBRE REGISTRADO EN LA BD"}]}{"Transferencia":[{"Notificacion":"1","Cantidad":"2","Nombre":"NOMBRE REGISTRADO EN LA BD"}]}`;

// Poner coma entre las dos llaves
str = str.replace('}{', '},{');

// Pero no es un json válido
let obj = JSON.parse(str); // Error
```

Hay que remplazar las dos llaves por una coma:

```js
let str = `{"Asignacion":[{"Notificacion":"1","Cantidad":"2","Nombre":"NOMBRE REGISTRADO EN LA BD"}]}{"Transferencia":[{"Notificacion":"1","Cantidad":"2","Nombre":"NOMBRE REGISTRADO EN LA BD"}]}`;

// Poner coma entre los dos elementos
str = str.replace('}{', ',');

// Pero no es un json válido
let obj = JSON.parse(str);

// Ahora ya puedes usar sus propiedades
console.log(obj.Asignacion);
console.log(obj.Transferencia);
```

Creo que lo ideal es que lo resuelvas desde PHP, donde probablemente estás enviando dos variables separadas, cada una codificada a JSON:

```
echo json_encode($asignacion);
echo json_encode($transferencia);
```

Puedes enviarlo en un solo elemento, encerrando ambas variables en un arreglo asociativo y generando sus respectivas propiedades:

```
echo json_encode([
    'Asignacion' => $asignacion['Asignacion'],
    'Transferencia' => $transferencia['Transferencia']
]);
```

Con esto evitarías tener que hacer "malabares" en Javascript.

Comment: Tengo una duda primero hago esto:  $resultadoTransferencia["Transferencia"][]=$registroTransferencia;  y luego tengo esto : echo json_encode($resultadoTransferencia); que es lo que me ha funcionado en cada consulta aislada.  Deja revisar tu aportación para ver como lo puedo adaptar.   Gracias

Comment: Agradezco el aporte, de momento preferí cambiar de estrategia, en cada petición Ajax, hago que mejor llame a su propio "archivo" de notificacion, y con ello me evito el estar arreglando los arreglos valga la redundancia.  No descarto la utilidad de este consejo que me aportas por eso te doy la palomita.